# Not able to find global log file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a script called `main.rb` in which I call modules. In the script, I am creating a log file (something like `\abc\xyz\script\tool.log`) and storing it in a global variable $LOG: `$LOG = Logger.new('tool.log', 'daily')`

From `main.rb` I call another module's method (say `HostM.changeDir1`) which changes directory to `\abc\xyz`. Now when I am trying to write into `$LOG` it errors out by printing `\abc\xyz\tool.log does not exist`. I was wondering how can I make it look for the log in proper location i.e., `\abc\xyz\script\tool.log`. Need guidance in fixing this issue.

Comment: `main.rb` cannot be a class name. `\abc\xyz\script\tool.log` cannot be a global variable.

Comment: My class name is `Main` and ruby script is called `main.rb`. Glabal variable is `$LOG = Logger.new('tool.log', 'daily')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the full path to the log file is one option

```
$LOG = Logger.new('\abc\xyz\script\tool.log', 'daily')
```

However, using a global variable is usually poor practice, and I expect using an absolute path is also going to cause problems if you move the app to another location. Therefore, I'd suggest you wrap the Logger in a new class that defines a standard behaviour and a path to the log file that is relative to the file where the new class is defined.

```
require 'logger'

class AppLogger < Logger
  def initialize(period = 'daily')
    path_to_log = File.expand_path('relative/path/to/tool.log', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    super path_to_log, period
  end
end
```

Then when you need a logger in your app, you can do this:

```
logger = AppLogger.new
logger.debug 'Whoops'
```

If you want to ensure you only work with one logger instance, I'd load the logger instance in your Main class, and share it from there:

```
class Main

  require_relative 'app_logger'

  def self.logger
    @logger ||= AppLogger.new
  end

  ....
end
```

Then in the rest of your app, you'll be able to call the logger like this:

```
 Main.logger.debug 'Whoops!'
```

Comment: I tried to have a `logger class`; `require` it from `Main class`; added `self.logger` method; added `require "main"` in `AppModule` and  then tried to call it from another module using `Main.logger.debug "hello"` but it failed by giving the following error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Main::AppModule`.

Comment: I expect that problem is due to the away AppModule is defined. I'd need to see that code to bug fix that.

Comment: As a temporary fix I am explicitly giving log file location but I would like to implement the solution suggested by you in my next version. I will spend some more time to see if I can fix it. Either ways I will post the piece of code. Thanks again!